# java filenames filter pattern

Tags: java, regex, filter, filenames

I need to implement

```
File[] files = getFiles( String folderName, String ptrn );
```

Where ptrn is a command prompt style pattern like "*2010*.txt"

I'm familar with FilenameFilter class, but can't implement 
`public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)`
because String.matches() doesn't accept such patterns.

Thanks!

Comment: What other patterns do you need to support?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`String#matches()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) accepts [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) [patterns](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

The regex variant of the "layman's" variant `*2010*.txt` would be `.*2010.*\.txt`.

So the following should work:

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.matches(".*2010.*\\.txt");
}
```

The double backslash is just there to represent an actual backslash because the backslash itself is an escape character in Java's `String`.

Alternatively, you can also do it without regex using the other `String` methods:

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.contains("2010") && name.endsWith(".txt");
}
```

Your best bet is likely to let `ptrn` represent a *real* regex pattern or to string-replace every `.` with `\.` and `*` with `.*` so that it becomes a valid regex pattern.

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.matches(ptrn.replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".*"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what would be the input pattern. It is not constant.
But based on your example I see that the following converts the patterns:

str.replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".*")

Comment: this is insufficient; if the string contains characters that have meaning in a regex, they are not escaped. (you covered the 'dot' character but there are others)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to scape your specific wild cards for those used in Java regex.

For instance to replace "*" you could use something like:

```
import java.io.*;

class Filter {
    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        String argPattern = args[0];

        final String pattern = argPattern.replace(".","\\.").replace("*",".*");
        System.out.println("transformed pattern = " + pattern );
        for( File f : new File(".").listFiles( new FilenameFilter(){
                           public boolean accept( File dir, String name ) { 
                               return name.matches( pattern );
                           }
                        })){
             System.out.println( f.getName() );
        }
    }
}


$ls -l *ter.*
-rw-r--r--  1 oscarreyes  staff  1083 Jun 16 17:55 Filter.class
-rw-r--r--  1 oscarreyes  staff   616 Jun 16 17:56 Filter.java
$java Filter "*ter.*"
transformed pattern = .*ter\..*
Filter.class
Filter.java
```

Comment: this is insufficient; if the string contains characters that have meaning in a regex, they are not escaped.

Comment: (most notably "." matches *any* character)