# How to search specific word in string

Tags: java

Please see the below code ,basically i am checking some specific word in filename to determine the type of file.Please see the below
code and leet me know if this is the best way otherwise please suggest.

```
Example File Name : incoming_EMP_data.dat
final String[] files = file.list();
if (files != null && files.length > 0) {                
fileName = files[0];
if(files[0].replace("_"," ").indexOf("EMP")!=-1)
System.out.println("EMP file");
else
System.out.println("NOT EMP file");
}
```

if file name has incoming_**TEMP**_data.dat also above code will pass,I am looking exact word ,

Regards,

mkr

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057621/java-filenames-filter-pattern - Take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

The filename has a pattern? I mean, will always come like "" ?

If yes, you can change your code to:

```
    if(files[0].indexOf("_EMP_") != -1)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Can for example be done with regular expressions and the word [boundary matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) `\b`:

```
String[] examples = {
        "incoming_EMP_data.dat",
        "EMP.pemp", // word boundary can be beginning or end
        "Hurz-EMP#poof", // many 
        "~EMP=", // many strange characters are boundaries
        "XYZ_TEMP.dat",
        "1EMP2", // numbers are considered word
        "ßEMPö" // unicode characters are also considered word
};

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bEMP\\b");
// word boundary EMP word boundary
// _ counts as part of a word though

for (String string : examples) {
    if(pattern.matcher(string.replace("_", " ")).find()) {
        System.out.println(string + " is EMP");
    } else {
        System.out.println(string + " is not.");
    }
}
```

prints

```
incoming_EMP_data.dat is EMP
EMP.pemp is EMP
Hurz-EMP#poof is EMP
~EMP= is EMP
XYZ_TEMP.dat is not.
1EMP2 is not.
ßEMPö is not.
```

The nice thing about `\b` is that it matches even when the word boundary is the beginning or end of the string. That's something not easily solved otherwise. `_` is unfortunately considered part of a word so you will either have to replace it (as done above) or extend the pattern to include it as alternative `"(\\b|_)EMP(\\b|_)"`.