# Java: Find all files and directories by mask

Tags: java, file

How to iterate through all files by mask in Java? For example, there's a mask with wild cards like

```
D:\work\mytestfolder\temp\*.txt
```

Need to get a collection (or iterator or whatever else) of all `*.txt` files in the directory above.

Some more details. Want to process a number of files and it's convenient here to define a set of masks like those shown above. The GLOBE syntax (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)) looks very helpful and would desirably be supported.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Now struggling with this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html. Seems too much complicated for so simple task.

Comment: @Alex, it's not actually that bad. In Java8 you have `Files::walk` which streams entities to you. So you split your mask on first wildcard, build a path from first part and a PathMatcher from second part, then start walking from the Path and filter the stream using PathMatcher.

Comment: have had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057621/java-filenames-filter-pattern. Not exactly what I need. Of cause we can implement our own solutions but I'd like to find something standard first. Also our hand-made solutions would desirably handle platform specifics, doesn't look like a simple task :(

Answer (score 1):

No need to create an explicit PathMatcher.  Just use [Files.newDirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-):

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(
        Paths.get("D:\\work\\mytestfolder\\temp"), "*.txt")) {

    for (Path entry : dir) {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It works and is convenient enough, thanks! Just need to get it to iterate also through the subdirectories of the starting directory (recursively).

Comment: For recursive traversal, you’ll want [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) or [Files.walkFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-).  Neither has a file mask option, but obviously it’s easy enough to check each file yourself.  The former method returns a Stream, so you can do `Files.walk(dir).filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p) && p.toString().endsWith(".txt"))`.

Comment: Cannot use Java 8, at least for now. So `Files.walkFileTree` with explicit `PathMatcher` seems to be the best choice... though really too verbose :(

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = new File("E:/Test");
File [] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
   @Override
   public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
      return name.endsWith(".chm");
   }
});

for (File xmlfile : files) {
    System.out.println(xmlfile);
}
```